# How to detect a zeroed value of struct safely in Go?

Tags: mysql, go

I tried to written an simple ORM for MySQL, I got a problem, if a defined struct missing some field:

```
type User struct {
    ID        int64
    Username  string
    Password  string
    Email     string
    Comment   string
}

var u = User{Username: "user_0001", Password: "password"}
```

Some fields of User didn't given a value, then it's value will be a zeroed value, such as string `""`, bool `false`, integer `0` and so on.

So I am using `reflect` to get field name and value, generate a sql to insert row.

`INSERT INTO User (Id, Username, Password, Email, Comment) Values (0, "user_0001",  "password", , ,)`

You can see there has some zeroed value of string, if I detect empty string `""` and skip them, I may skip normal value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle database columns that may be `NULL`, you can either use pointers as Friedrich Große suggests, or use the `Null...`-variants found in the `db` package, for instance [`sql.NullString`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString).

To use the Null-variants, the struct would be

```
type User struct {
    ID        int64
    Username  string
    Password  string
    Email     sql.NullString
    Comment   sql.NullString
}
```

You can then detect of a value is set by checking `NullString.Valid`. The downside of using `NullString` is that you have to add special cases when printing or marshaling them, as they don't implement the [`Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface, nor `MarshalJSON` or `UnmarshalJSON`. You also have to remember to set `NullString.Valid` manually when setting the value of the string.

For instance, a test like

```
func TestNullString(t *testing.T) {
    s := sql.NullString{}
    t.Log(s)

    s.String = "Test"
    s.Valid = true
    t.Log(s)
}
```

Prints

```
null_string_test.go:21: { false}
null_string_test.go:25: {Test true}
```

To print a `NullString` you have to instead do

```
func TestNullString(t *testing.T) {
    s := sql.NullString{}
    t.Log(s.String)

    s.String = "Test"
    s.Value = true
    t.Log(s.String)
}
```

Which prints:

```
null_string_test.go:21: 
null_string_test.go:25: Test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always just insert an empty string into your table column. If it is truly important to know the difference between the zero value or complete absence of a value you would need to use pointers.

```
type User struct {
    ID        int64
    Username  *string
}
```

This changes the zero value to be `nil` so you can distinguish that from `""`.
The downside is that this makes this type less easy to use (`nil` checks are often forgotten in practice) and you have to dereference that field to get the actual string.

In your specific example I don't see why you need to worry about the empty value at all. Can't you just insert `""` into the database and enforce validation (non-emptiness) in your code instead of using database constraints?